# What is this piece?

Tags: part-identification

I found this in my lego collection and can't find the name or id of the piece.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9):

This is part #30092

[Minifigure, Utensil Underwater Scooter Octagonal with Handles](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30092#T=C&C=3)

In black, it appears in [three sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=30092&colorID=11&in=A)